# Data format in EtherCAT is it only oriented process?

Tags: ethercat

I Want to know if EtherCAT can be used in other scenarios than process management, like transferring video for example.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

`EtherCAT` is a communication protocol to transfer data at a very high speed.  At the moment it is only used for high speed automation and other industrial applications.  I have not found any evidence of it used otherwise.

Comment: Yes, but if we switch the industrial data with something else, does it work ? i searched and i can't see what can go wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can define your own format -- the so called vendor-specific protocol over EtherCAT (VoE) or use File over EtherCAT (FoE) in order to transfer separate video frames.